# Getting user and encrypted password from datebase

Tags: php, mysql, select, bind, statements

i got the following code:

```
    public function getUserByNameAndPassword($name, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT salt FROM `users` WHERE name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $stmt->store_result();
            $salt = $stmt->get_result();
            } 
    $encryptedpassword = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt,$password);

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE name = ? AND encrypted_password = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $encryptedpassword);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
                $stmt->close();
                return $user;
            } 
            else {
                return false;
        }

}
```

And the following constructor:

```
    // constructor
function __construct() {
    require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
    // connecting to database
    $db = new Db_Connect();
    $this->conn = $db->connect();
}
```

I'm trying to get user from datebase but it is not working at all, i already tried many things, checked my syntax multiple times but i can't find my mistake. Anybody has an idea?

Edit: Changed code and added log but the log doesent report anything.

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i know about the risk of SQL injection, i also tried it with the second method but it wasnt working. I'm pretty much a newbie to PHP and SQL, so sorry for my inconveniance.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You have multiple syntax errors (like `$this->conn->prepare`)